# VPC Rekognition endpoint for use with Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc

I have a Lambda function that needs to connect to S3, RDS, and Rekognition.  Obviously this means putting it in a VPC, which of course kills internet access (thanks AWS....)

I was able to maintain access to S3 by simply creating a networking endpoint to `com.amazonaws.us-east-2.s3`.  This prevented me from having to create a Gateway, as I refuse to pay $33 a month simply for my Lambda function to access the internet....

But, are there really no endpoints that will work with Rekognition? I didn't see anything obvious, but I'm really out of my comfort zone as it is dealing with VPC networking, so I wanted to double check to see if any of the other 45 endpoints would work, or if anyone has come up with any work-arounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Sep 12, 2019, AWS announced:

> Starting today, AWS customers can **use AWS PrivateLink to access Amazon Rekognition from their Amazon Virtual Private Cloud (Amazon VPC) without using public IPs**, and without requiring the traffic to traverse across the Internet. Amazon Rekognition lets customers easily add intelligent image and video analysis to their applications. AWS PrivateLink provides private connectivity between VPCs and AWS services, without ever leaving the Amazon network.

See: [Announcing AWS PrivateLink support for Amazon Rekognition](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/09/announcing-aws-privatelink-support-for-amazon-rekognition/)

Comment: well, $7 a month is better than $33